# Prolog: <name>:compile(Filename) usage and explanation

Tags: prolog

What's the meaning of the following code in `prolog`

```
  evaluate:compile(EvaluateFile),
```

I didn't find any definition for `evaluate` in the context.

My guess is `compile EvaluateFile into a module named evaluate`, is that accurate?

Thank you!

---

*I am trying to migrate an earlier code to `SWI-Prolog`, which was written in
`SICStus 3 #3: Thu Sep 12 09:54:27 CDT 1996` or earlier
by Raymond J. Mooney ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/mooney/chill/. 
All the questions with this tag are all related to this task. I'm new to prolog, helps and suggestions are welcomed!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

You will find that trying to load the code in a recent SWI-Prolog version will result in a number of compilation errors. A good number of those errors occur when trying to load the `chill_lib.pl` file. Most of them are easy to fix, however, and result from the `lists` and `random` module libraries already exporting some of the predicates defined in the `chill_lib` module. Just comment them out. There's also a definition for the standard predicate `once/1` that you need to comment out. The `library(timeout)` doesn't exist in SWI-Prolog but there's a `library(time)` providing similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! It seems running on `yap` requires less effort than `swi-prolog`, but both have issues due to unknown problems. I removed a lot of duplicate definitions from the code `chill_lib`. I will post other questions when I meet new problems.